# Reset default branch in Mercurial/TortoiseHG

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I pulled from the `newfeatures` branch in one of my Mercurial repos using TortoiseHg. Now whenever I try to pull from ANY of my repos, it tries to use the `newfeatures` branch, which doesn't exist on any of my other repos.

I cannot find any setting to let me fix this. I uninstalled TortoiseHG and reinstalled it and the problem still occurs. I deleted all my local repos and tried recloning them and the problem still occurs.

My Mercurial.ini does not specify a branch. If I go into the console and type `hg branch` it reports `default`. TortoiseHg workbench says `Branch: default` above `selected options` and the selected options are `--pushafter = True` . However, every time I try to pull, the output log reads `hg pull --verbose --branch newfeatures`.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Could it be because of the `Target` check box in the Synchronize panel? Even if the panel is not visible, the `Pull` button uses those settings when TortoiseHg issues the `hg pull` command.

[image: <code>Target</code> check box]